# How to compare two different columns data regardless the order in different text files?

Tags: python, arrays

Want to do this,

Input1 (Text file 1)

```
ABCD,  QI30  
FGDE,  Q140  
KLOM,  Q232   
..      ..  
..      ..   
..      ..
```

Input2 (Text file 2)

```
DATA: ARRAY: KLOM: n: 000000000111111110011111111111111111111111  
DATA: ARRAY: ABCD: n: 000111111111111111101111111111111111111111  
DATA: ARRAY: FGDE: n: 010101010111111111111111111111111111111111  
..      ..  
..      ..   
..      ..
```

Output( write in text file 3)

```
Item=Q232; Var:KLOM    
read_Var:read_q232: Get_Data: n: 000000000111111110011111111111111111111111  

Item=Q130; Var:ABCD  
read_Var:read_q150: Get_Data: n: 000111111111111111101111111111111111111111  

Item=Q140; Var:FGDE  
read_Var:read_q170: Get_Data: n: 010101010111111111111111111111111111111111   
..      ..  
..      ..   
..      ..
```

This is part of the code,

```
import collections

#Create a data dict using textfile1.txt
with open("textfile1.txt") as f1:   
    # create generator of entries using non-empty lines in file
    entries1 = (line.split() for line in f1 if line.strip())
    # create dict using ($1) as key and $2 as value
    data1 = dict(((d[0], d[1]) for d in entries1)

with open("textfile2.txt") as f2:   
    entries2 = (line.split() for line in f2 if line.strip())
    data2 = dict(((f[2], f[3]), f[4]) for f2 in entries2)

   set(d[1]) == set(f[2]) # compare the text file1 column 2 with text file2 column 3
```

After this point, I don't know how to do already. Really I need u guys help.

Comment: what language? It looks like python but I have no idea.  please edit your post with the right language tag if you want the right type of programmers to see your post.

Comment: Ya ya, its python language @Clayton

Comment: A good start would be to explain what you want to do, indent your code properly, and make sure the number of right parenthesis equals the number of left parenthesis.  None of which you've done yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces the desired output:

```
ids = {}
with open('input1.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        if line.strip():
            key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
            ids[key] = value

arrays = []
with open('input2.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        if line.strip():
            values = [x.strip() for x in line.split(':')]
            arrays.append((values[2], values[3:]))

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    for key, values in arrays:
        item = ids[key]
        fobj.write('Item={}; Var:{}\n'.format(item, key))
        fobj.write('read_Var:read_{}: Get_Data: {}\n\n'.format(item.lower(),
                                                            ':'.join(values)))
```

Comment: This is additional question regarding the above question.  If the column 3 in 'input2.txt' has 'sssss' string in a list and need to convert to '00000'.How am going to do it?  This is part of the code.      with open('output.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    for key, values in arrays:
        item = ids[key]
  new_values = string.replace(values[3:],'sssss','000000')
        fobj.write('Item={}; Var:{}\n'.format(item, key))
        fobj.write('read_Var:read_{}: Get_Data: {}\n\n'.format(item.lower(),
                                                            ':'.join(values)))

Comment: @Noorul It is difficult to answer a question in a comment. Please create new question with sample input and desired output and reference it here. I will have look.