# How to convert 's' string in a list to 0 in python?

Tags: python

This question is a followed-up of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302994/how-to-compare-two-different-columns-data-regardless-the-order-in-different-text). You need to read to understand the problem here.

Want to do this,

Input1 (Text file 1)

```
ABCD,  QI30  
FGDE,  Q140  
KLOM,  Q232   
..      ..  
..      ..   
..      ..
```

Input2(Text file 2)

```
DATA: ARRAY: KLOM: n: 00000000011111111001111111ssss111111111111  
DATA: ARRAY: ABCD: n: 000111111111111111101111111111111sss111111  
DATA: ARRAY: FGDE: n: 01010101011111111sssssss111111111111111111  
 ..      ..  
 ..      ..   
 ..      ..
```

Output

```
Item=Q232; Var:KLOM    
read_Var:read_q232: Get_Data: n: 00000000011111111001111111ssss111111111111  

Item=Q130; Var:ABCD  
read_Var:read_q150: Get_Data: n: 000111111111111111101111111111111sss111111  

Item=Q140; Var:FGDE  
read_Var:read_q170: Get_Data: n: 01010101011111111sssssss111111111111111111   
..      ..  
..      ..   
..      ..  

Item=Q232; Data:KLOM    
read_Data:burn_q232: Get_Data: n: 000000000111111110011111110000111111111111  

Item=Q130; Data:ABCD  
read_Data:burn_q150: Get_Data: n: 000111111111111111101111111111111000111111  

Item=Q140; Data:FGDE  
read_Data:burn_q170: Get_Data: n: 010101010111111110000000111111111111111111  
..      ..  
..      ..   
..      ..
```

The 'ssss' string in column3 input2 text file is replaced with '0000' and write as an output in second paragraph in output file.

This is the part of code that I modified:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fobj:
for key, values in arrays:
    item = ids[key]
    new_values = string.replace(values[3:],'s','0')
    fobj.write('Item={}; Var:{}\n'.format(item, key))
    fobj.write('read_Var:read_{}: Get_Data: {}\n\n'.format(item.lower(),
                                                        ':'.join(new_values)))
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the last entry in the list `values` and do the replace on it:

```
values[-1] = values[-1].replace('s', '0')
```

The whole loop:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    for key, values in arrays:
        values[-1] = values[-1].replace('s', '0')
        item = ids[key]
        fobj.write('Item={}; Var:{}\n'.format(item, key))
        fobj.write('read_Var:read_{}: Get_Data: {}\n\n'.format(item.lower(),
                                                            ':'.join(values)))
```

Output:

```
Item=Q232; Var:KLOM
read_Var:read_q232: Get_Data: n:000000000111111110011111110000111111111111

Item=QI30; Var:ABCD
read_Var:read_qi30: Get_Data: n:000111111111111111101111111111111000111111

Item=Q140; Var:FGDE
read_Var:read_q140: Get_Data: n:010101010111111110000000111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `string`? Anyway this should do what you want

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    for key, values in arrays:
        item = ids[key]
        new_values = values[-1].replace('s','0')
        fobj.write('Item={}; Var:{}\n'.format(item, key))
        fobj.write('read_Var:read_{}: Get_Data: {}\n\n'.format(item.lower(),':'.join(new_values)))
```

string is python module for string manipulation, however your error says `list`. So I assume string contains some kind of list.

If any you might need to look into `str`. The equivalent syntax would be

```
    new_values = str.replace(values[-1],'s','0')
```